# Cast reified generic type as non-null with Any upper bound

Tags: kotlin, generics, casting, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I’m trying to use a reified type parameter to check if the type argument is nullable, returning a different class implementation based on the nullability of the type argument. This works well, except for the non-null subclass requiring its generic type to have a non-null `Any` upper bound, in order to have a `KClass<T>` constructor argument.

This code works as expected:

```
interface Test
class NullableT<T> : Test
class NonNullT<T> : Test

inline fun <reified T> test(): Test {
    return if (null is T) {
        NullableT<T>()
    } else {
        NonNullT<T>()
    }
}

test<String?>()::class.simpleName // NullableT
test<String>()::class.simpleName  // NonNullT
```

However, this code has a compiler error:

```
interface Test
class NullableT<T> : Test
class NonNullT<T : Any>(tClass: KClass<T>) : Test

inline fun <reified T> test(): Test {
    return if (null is T) {
        NullableT<T>()
    } else {
        NonNullT<T>(T::class) // <-- error with <T>
        // Type argument is not within its bounds. Expected: Any Found: T
    }
}
```

Following the check for `!(null is T)`, there needs to be some way to cast `T` as having a non-null `Any` upper bound.

It’s possible to make a non-null `T` optional. This works:

```
interface Test
class NullableT<T> : Test
class NonNullT<T : Any> : Test

inline fun <reified T : Any> test(nullable: Boolean): Test {
    return if (nullable) {
        NullableT<T?>()
    } else {
        NonNullT<T>()
    }
}

test<String>(true)::class.simpleName // NullableT
test<String>(false)::class.simpleName // NonNullT
```

But I need a way to make a nullable `T` non-null. This isn’t valid:

```
interface Test
class NullableT<T> : Test
class NonNullT<T : Any> : Test

inline fun <reified T> test(nullable: Boolean): Test {
    return if (nullable) {
        NullableT<T>()
    } else {
        NonNullT<T!!>() // Type parameter 'T' is not an expression
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) works:

```
import kotlin.reflect.*
interface Test
class NullableT<T> : Test
class NonNullT<T : Any>(tClass: KClass<T>) : Test

inline fun <reified T> test(dummy: Nothing? = null): Test {
    return NullableT<T>()
}
inline fun <reified T: Any> test(): Test {
    return NonNullT<T>(T::class)
}


fun main(){
    println(test<Any>().toString())
    println(test<Any?>().toString())
    println(test<String>().toString())
    println(test<String?>().toString())
}
```

"But why does this work?" I hear you asking. Well simply, what's happening here is that the Kotlin compiler prefers functions that match the number of passed in parameters (in this case 0) over functions that have default parameters that would result in allowing the number of passed in parameters (in other words, if you call a function with 1 argument, the compiler will prefer a function with 1 parameter over a function with 2 parameters where the 2nd parameter has a default value). However, because T has a different upper bound in the 2 functions, if the type that you're trying to invoke `test` with doesn't follow the upper bound of the preferred function (which in this case is the one that returns `NonNullT`), the compiler will fall back to calling the more broad `test` function (i.e. the one that returns `NullableT`).
This solution is kinda hacky, but sadly I don’t think there’s any other way to implement it.

Comment: True, this is hacky, but could still work, except it doesn't in Kotlin 1.3.72 unfortunately. It fails to compile with `Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Any'`. It still tries to use the no-argument function, even though the type isn't within the bounds. Changing the call to `test<Any?>(null)` forces it to call the working function. It works in 1.4-M2 and 1.4-M3, which would be promising for possibly eventually working when 1.4 is released, except it also doesn't compile in 1.4.0-RC.

Comment: Oh yeah right. I was testing this on 1.4-M2 I think. I'm gonna try to find a solution for 1.3, cuz there probably is one.

Comment: it seems like the RC version on the Kotlin Playground was a bit broken because now if you run it again using the RC version (which they have, for some reason, renamed to rc instead lol), it complies and works perfectly. My guess is that they had the new type inference algorithm turned off by mistake, but it was actually supposed to be turned on for all 1.4 versions. So yeah, now my Jacky approach actually works and can even work for any arbritary upper bound. Please try it out and tell me if you find any problems

Comment: That's good to see the new inference functionality will work consistently going forward with the release of 1.4. I hadn't seen the RC version officially released yet, so that probably explains why the build keeps changing in the playground.

Comment: It is officially released: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-released/ They probably just had some config errors or something on the playground. You can also use the 1.4 version in a project by specifying it in the build.gradle (keep in mind that you also need to add the Kotlin EAP bintray as a source of Gradle dependencies) or just wait until 1.4 comes out.

Comment: Oh, cool. Missed that announcement yesterday. Makes sense the timing around it showing up in the playground I guess. I'll probably wait until GA to use it in production, but good to see it's coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add dynamic type bound to type parameter since it can be checked only at compile-time because of type erasure.

Kotlin Nullability feature doesn't exist at compile-time too.

Comment: [Reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) in Kotlin are available at runtime. Type erasure doesn't apply here, which is why the working code in my question works as it does.

Comment: But class generics are not reified

Comment: However, you can store KClass<*> inside NullableT and NonNullT instead of type and check nullability of KClass.

Comment: It makes sense the class generics aren't available at runtime. But the issue is that the compiler is blocking the code from compiling, even though the runtime check of the reified type guarantees the safety of instantiating the class that has a non-null `Any` upper bound. The compiler could smart cast the type after this check. Or a mechanism for casting the upper bound of the reified type to manually signal to the compiler this is safe is needed.

Comment: Values can be smart casted, type parameters can't. (it would be a nice feature, but it requires language to have some compile-time logic operating on types)

Comment: I could change the constructor parameter to `KClass<*>` and lose the type safety checks, having to cast the usage to `T` explicitly. But at least that will compile.